# What should I use to lubricate my kickstand?

Tags: maintenance, lubricant, kickstand

The kickstand that came with my bike is rusty and is difficult to adjust. What should I use for lubrication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grease. You want a lubricant that will stick around. WD40 is a degreaser and is designed to penetrate, lubricate then evaporate. Which is great for removing something that's stuck. But for a kickstand you want it to keep working for a long time. So, grease.

Comment: This is what I used and it worked. I had to grease around the kickstand and the spring.

Answer (score 0):

"White grease".  This is, as it sounds, a grease that is white.  Comes in "toothpaste" tubes and spray cans.  An auto store will know what you mean.

A little dab 'll do ya.

Answer (score -3):

GT85*, with excess removed :-)

*Or equivalent, even WD40 will suffice.